# WebStorm doesn't pick up text copied to buffer

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

Occasionally I copy text and try to paste this text into WebStorm, but WebStorm doesn't pick up that copied text, although this text can be pasted into other varies text processor. This happens to all members of our team.

Is this some known issue? I tried to google it but haven't found any mentioning of this problem.

Comment: also happend to me several times in intellij. Does a restart of the ide helped?

Comment: @TobiasTimm, yes, it usually helps

Comment: okay, maybe we should raise a bug ticket. I think it affects the whole plattform, because we are using intellij and i occured the same behaviour

Comment: yeah, indeed, I also think it affects the entire platform

Comment: Your OS and IDE versions (build numbers)?

Comment: @LazyOne, Windows 10, Build WS-143.1559 built on December, 23 2015. I believe I also had the issue on Windows 7

Comment: If I understand this correctly then it should be fixed in PhpStorm 2016.1.1 final / WebStorm 2016.1.2 or newer (not current **EAP** build). In meantime (for your v10/v11) -- try this one: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-143603#comment=27-1370608

Comment: @LazyOne, thanks a lot for your help, I've replaced the .dll's, will see how it goes. Best of luck! Do you represent IDEA in some way? You seem to be answering all my questions re IDEA :)

Comment: @LazyOne, tried the approach with libraries, didn't work for me since for some reason with different .dll's git bash terminal doesn't work. Will try `Ctrl+C` approach then

Comment: @Maximus It is possible (after re-reading that ticket + your comment) that the new library will not work well with previous version of WebStorm that you are currently using. Have you tried updating to the latest 2016.1 version (you can run in parallel at least for testing purposes)? It should work there (few people confirmed that).

Comment: @I think I'd need to buy a new license to get upgraded from the current version, or am I wrong? And also repeating my question _Do you represent IDEA in some way?_

Comment: @Maximus 1) It depends on your current license. But if your subscription is not yet expired then no need for purchase. In any case -- you can always try in in trial mode. 2) No

Comment: thanks, indeed my current subsription is still active and allowed me to install new version